# Getting dynamic array from inside a function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function that allows me to perform sql queries depending on what type of SQL server the user has chosen.  The function works fine getting a single row of data, but it never returns more than 1 row.

This is the sql function:

```
function sqlQuery($query){
switch (DATABASE_TYPE) {
    case 'MYSQL':
        // Establishes a connection to the database.
        $connection = mysql_connect(DATABASE_LOCATION, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        if(!$connection){
            throw new Exception(mysql_error(), 1);
        }
        mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Performs the query.
        global $response;
        $response = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$response){
            throw new Exception(mysql_error(), 1);
        }
        return mysql_fetch_array($response);
        break;
    }
}
```

And like I said above, this works just fine for single row queries, but I can't get any more.

If I try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test"
$rows = sqlQuery($sql);
foreach($rows as $value){
    echo($value);
}
```

If row 1 of test is `1 | Hello | PHP` it would echo `11HelloHelloPHPPHP`

Answer (score 0):

it is simple to do it

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
$data = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $data[] = $rows ;
}

return $data;
```

Comment: I can't use any database type specific methods like mysql_fetch as this application needs to work with other sql server types.

Comment: this is only an example of doing in mysql and ofcourse you will be doing it in case 'MYSQL' for other sql server types you will be playing with inside CASE

Answer (score 0):

To shed a little more light on raheel's answer, mysql_fetch_array only returns a single row of results. Using a while loop allows you to continue to grab additional rows as long as they exist. For additional information, you may want to look at [Getting dynamic array from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908843/getting-dynamic-array-from-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more number of rows you have to use forloop to get all the rows.. that is it will return as resourceid #-- please print_r or echo your result and check it.. after that use that result inside mysql_fetch_row ~ mysql_fetch_array ~ antything else you want.. and store it in array with its id as key... please check the following edited code,

```
function sqlQuery($query){
switch (DATABASE_TYPE) {
    case 'MYSQL':
        // Establishes a connection to the database.
        $connection = mysql_connect(DATABASE_LOCATION, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        if(!$connection){
            throw new Exception(mysql_error(), 1);
        }
        mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Performs the query.
        global $response;
        $response = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$response){
            throw new Exception(mysql_error(), 1);
        }
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $data[$rows['id]] =  $rows;
        }
        return $data;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing what type of data is returning from:

`return mysql_fetch_array($response);`

to:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($response)){
    array_push($rows, $row);
}
return $rows;
```

Thanks for all your help!